# Looking for an embeddable (C / C++ for Linux) HTTP client & server library with range seek and chunked response support

Tags: library, c, streaming, http, server

I'm trying to implement an application with HTTP client for receiving audio stream (mp3, chunked, with byte range seek) and serving it as a SHOUTcast compatible stream.

Do you know any good library which includes both HTTP 1.1 client and server, supports reading from chunked responses and seeking, implemented in C/C++ and lightweight enough to be used on a Raspberry-like device?

Here is a list of more popular candidates I have collected, but I'm not sure which one would be the most appropriate:

Libmicrohttpd (C)
Pion Network Library (C++)
libhttpd (C)
libsoup (C)
neon (C)
libWWW (C)
EHS (C++)
mihl (C)
libebb (C)
tntnet (C++)
libonion (C)
Mongoose (C)
Mimosa (C++)
libevhtp (C)
libasyncd (C)
goahead (C)
appweb (C)

In case you have successfully used one of these for a media streaming proxy project, I'd be grateful for sharing your experiences.